# Use CurrentLocation for Continent iPhone

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, location, cllocationmanager

Is there a way to find out the users location Continent? I need to set an AWS entry point based on if they open the app in the US, or Europe. etc.

Is there a way to do this without taking GPS coordinates and making ranges out of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in iOS5, you can use GLGeocoder to retrieve the information abotu a current location:

```
[self.CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         //placemark contains the address

}];
```

CLPlacemark reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html

GLGeocoder reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

you can reverse geocode a location and get details of where the user is located in text. You use the `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` method on the [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) class to do this

The completion handler in this method gets passed in an array of `CLPlacemark` objects, which contain the country code, which you can use to determine the users continent

Answer (score 0):

Although a CLPlacemark object contains lots of useful information, its corresponding continent is not present on it.

I wrote a small category to add a -continent method that returns the corresponding string of the continent based on the -ISOCountryCode of a CLPlacemark.

https://github.com/Hecktorzr/Transcontinental